# How to give a \t space in php

Tags: javascript, php

Q.1)Write a Program to display in php

```
Expected Output:

Hello
      Welcome to PHP
                 VLABS




program:

<?php
$f="Hello";
$s="Welcome to PHP";
$t="VLABS";

echo ($f."\n");
echo "\t".$s."\n";
echo "\t\t".$t."\n";

?>
```

I tried the above code it works fine in cmd but as i view it in browser it appears in  a single line
[Image shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YasiS.png)

how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the PHP in a `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre><?php
$f="Hello";
$s="Welcome to PHP";
$t="VLABS";

echo ($f."\n");
echo "\t".$s."\n";
echo "\t\t".$t."\n";

?>
</pre>
```